# What is the distribution of the maximum of two random integers chosen from [1,n]?

Tags: probability, random-variable

Suppose we have the set of integers from 1 to n. We proceed to choose two integers from this set at random and denote S = maximum of these two integers. What is the distribution of the random variable S?

Comment: Presumably this is sampling without replacement?  Also, this looks a lot like homework and so please read the [tag info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for the `self-study` tag, _add_ this tag if appropriate, and edit your question to conform.

Answer (score 1):

The let the result be $\{i,j\}$ where $i\neq j$ and $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. There are $(n-1)n$ pairs - imagine a matrix without diagonal.

The cases when the result will be $k$ are $k+k-1-1=2k-2$. Imagine in the matrix the cells with this result: they start at $(i,j)=(1,k)$, then $(2,k),\dots(k-1,k)$ and symetrically $(i,j)=(k,1)$, then $(k,2),\dots(k,k-1)$. Thus the probability is
$$
P(\max(i,j)=k)=\frac{2k-2}{(n-1)n}\textrm{.}
$$